# IBM Watson NLU - Understanding is being blocked by robots.txt

Tags: watson, watson-nlu

I'm using the IBM Watson Natural Language API to scan specific webpage to determine keywords and categories.

But I've run into a issue with some sites which have their robots.txt set to block website scanner.

I'm working directly with these sites and they added the Watson agent string of "watson-url-fetcher" to their robots.txt file.

The result is that this works only some of the time.

This simplified robots.txt file works:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
User-agent: watson-url-fetcher
Disallow: /manager/
```

But if the order is changed, the Watson no longer works:
reordered robots.txt fails :

```
User-agent: watson-url-fetcher
Disallow: /manager/
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Watson then return the error code:
{
  "error": "request to fetch blocked: fetch_failed",
  "code": 400
}

Is this an error with Watson, or do I need to instruct the websites to always put the User-agent: * at the top of the robots.txt file?

Comment: I do not know if this is a standard, but Google specifically mention in their documentation that the order does not matter. I suppose Watson should use the same principle. "The order of the groups within the robots.txt file is irrelevant."
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt#order-of-precedence-for-user-agents